# What value does System.Drawing.Color -state have?

Tags: c#, struct, equality, system.drawing, base-class-library

System.Drawing.Color has a private field `int state` which makes equality a bit more tricky than one would expect from a struct.

Anyone know what on earth it's for? Who, what and why sets and reads it?

Comment: color just has a empty field.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14w97wkc.aspx

Comment: My understanding is that the Color structure just has an `empty` field. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_fields.aspx. But in .NET 3.5 it appears to be used internally as CSharpie mentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i understand, it is compared to theese values:

```
    private static short StateKnownColorValid   = 0x0001;
    private static short StateARGBValueValid    = 0x0002;
    private static short StateValueMask         = (short)(StateARGBValueValid);
    private static short StateNameValid         = 0x0008;
    private static long NotDefinedValue = 0;
```

http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Color@cs/1/Color@cs

So my shot is that its used to dertermine if its a "System Color" or a user defined from e.g. ARGB values.

```
public bool IsKnownColor 
{
    get { return((state & StateKnownColorValid) != 0);}
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. :) Should've decompiled myself..
Have to dig around a bit more the next time I hit my head against ==..

Answer (score 1):

The `Color` struct overrides the `Equals` method and does therefore automatically do the right thing when colors are tested for equality.

The `Equals` method compares the `value`, `state`, `knownColor` and `name` fields.